# Convert cURL headers to Delphi TIdHTTP

Tags: delphi, curl, idhttp

I am trying to address the OriginStamp.org site to post a file hash and to get its timestamp

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" http://api.originstamp.org/api/yyyyyyyyyyy
```

I used various formats to access this API but this seemed to be most hopeful but with out success

```
PROCEDURE TInterNetFm.GetTIMESTAMP;
var
    i           : integer;
    response    : string;
    JSONToSend  : TStringStream;
    IndyH       : TIdHTTP;
begin
    IndyH       := TIdHTTP.Create(Application);
    JSONToSend  := TStringStream.Create('{}');
    IndyH.Request.Connection := 'Keep-Alive';
    IndyH.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
    IndyH.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Content-Type'] := 'application/json';
    IndyH.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization']:='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    IndyH.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
    response:=IdHttp1.post('http://originstamp.org/api/
        05c2422f44ddd24ba3f25848773a8fcb48435f8f966381da4732c40a7255780c', 
        JSONToSend); 
    JSONToSend.free;
    IndyH.free;
    end;
```

This gives a HTTP/1.1 error 403 forbidden.
I have also tried `IdHttp1.get`and the Delphi REST debugger and various attampts at REST.

Any suggestions about how I am going wrong with this would be grately appreciated.

Comment: I sure hope that long string in your question isn't something important and sensitive... If so, it's too late. Even if you delete this question, it can still be seen. Be more careful next time.

Answer (score 1):

A 403 error implies that you are likely using an invalid API key in the `Authorization` header.  Also, make sure that `Request.BasicAuthentication` is set to False so `TIdHTTP` doesn't try to send its own `Authorization` header.

That being said, I see several other issues with your code.

You are leaking memory if `TIdHTTP.Post()` raises an exception on failure.

You are sending 2 `Content-Type` headers (one from `Request.ContentType` and the other from `CustomerHeaders.Values['Content-Type']`). Use `Request.ContentType` only.

You are sending your request to `originstamp.org` when you should be sending it to `api.originstamp.org` instead.

You are creating and configuring a `TIdHTTP` object named `IndyH`, but you are performing the actual `Post()` using another object named `IdHttp1` instead.

Try this:

```
function TInterNetFm.GetTIMESTAMP(const AHash: string): string;
var
  IndyH : TIdHTTP;
  Response : string;
begin
  IndyH := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    IndyH.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
    IndyH.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'YOUR_API_KEY';
    Response := IndyH.Get('http://api.originstamp.org/api/' + AHash); 
  finally
    IndyH.Free;
  end;
  // parse Response JSON as needed...
  Result := ...;
end;
```

```
function TInterNetFm.GetTIMESTAMP(const AHash, AData: string): string;
var
  IndyH : TIdHTTP;
  JSONToSend : TStringStream;
  Response : string;
begin
  IndyH := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    IndyH.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
    IndyH.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
    IndyH.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'YOUR_API_KEY';
    JSONToSend := TStringStream.Create(AData, TEncoding.UTF8);
    try
      Response := IndyH.Post('http://api.originstamp.org/api/' + AHash, JSONToSend);
    finally
      JSONToSend.Free;
    end;
  finally
    IndyH.Free;
  end;
  // parse Response JSON as needed...
  Result := ...;
end;
```

Comment: for `function TInterNetFm.GetTIMESTAMP(const AHash: string): string;`, I still get the 403 error.   However, I have got REST debugger working and returning the correct data.  For this I

Comment: Then I suggest you contact OriginStamp for futher help with their API. The code is following their documentation, so it might be a server issue. You can capture the HTTP request that `TIdHTTP` sends by using a packet sniffer like Wireshark, or attaching a `TIdLog...` component to `TIdHTTP`, such as `TIdLogFile`, and send it to OriginStamp to review.

Comment: I have got REST debugger working using "GET" + base URL, Content-Type = application/json, PARAMETERS, Resource, the hash;  Request parameters (1) [HEADER] Authorization = API_KEY; (2) [HEADER] Content-Type = application/JSon.    These settings returned all the predicted JSON information    Does this help in troubleshooting..  Thanks

Comment: No, it doesn't, because 1) I don't use Embarcadero's REST framework, and 2) it doesn't explain the difference between the *actual* HTTP request that REST sends to the server vs the *actual* HTTP request that `TIdHTTP` sends.  You need to capture both requests and compare them for differences, and then you can apply whatever changes you need to `TIdHTTP` to make them match. For all I know, it could be something stupid like the server rejecting `TIdHTTP`'s default `User-Agent` header, for instance (some servers have been known to do that!)